# how to run arm64 docker images on amd64 host platform

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, apple-m1

getting the following error upon attempting to run an image created on my mac m1 to the Docker playground website

`WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested`

is there a way to make it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed to the test the `linux/arm64` version of a multiarch image on my Ubuntu(`linux/amd64`) laptop, just to ensure that it works. When I initially tried to run it, after pulling it using `docker pull --platform=linux/arm64 <image-name>`, I got the below error:

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
exec /bin/sh: exec format error
```

Then I installed [qemu-user-static](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static) as per one of the instructions on this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/c75uhq/how_to_run_arm64_containers_from_amd64_hosts_and/). After that, I was able to run the `linux/arm64` image on my x86 laptop. The reddit post has instructions like installing binaries other than `qemu-user-static` and also mounting the `qemu-user-static` binary into the container as a volume in the `docker run` command. I didn't need to do any of that. Just needed to install `qemu-user-static`(and maybe `binfmt-support`, which was already installed in my laptop) which I did using `sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static`.

Comment: Any performance comparison? How many times is slower? For instance how long this takes `time dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1024 count=10000` on amd64 and arm64 images?

Comment: I don't have a personal ARM machine, so will try to test this in CI whenever I have some time. I do have a few personal projects where I build and test separate(or multi-arch) amd64 and arm64 images. I have noticed that the arm64 containers are consistently faster. Sample builds [here](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/devatherock/ldap-search-api?branch=master). In the last 10 builds, average time taken for tests was 63 seconds for amd64 and 51 seconds for arm64. The tests are run in similar sized VMs - 2 CPU/7.5 GB RAM for amd64 and 2 CPU/8 GB RAM for arm64

Answer (score 1):

Can you share how you are building your image with us please?

You can [build multi arch images from a single host](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/), but you will need to ensure that you pass the correct flags to to Docker when building. In your case, you will need to target `linux/amd64` in order to get it to run on the host you are targeting.

The example included in the above article is as such, using `docker buildkit`:

```
~/test ❯❯❯ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t adamparco/demo:latest --push .
```

Or if you have not enabled buildkit yet (I think it's on be default with docker desktop now), you can use the old way via [docker manifests](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/), per this example:

```
# AMD64
$ docker build -t your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-amd64 --build-arg ARCH=amd64/ .
$ docker push your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-amd64

# ARM32V7
$ docker build -t your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-arm32v7 --build-arg ARCH=arm32v7/ .
$ docker push your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-arm32v7

# ARM64V8
$ docker build -t your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-arm64v8 --build-arg ARCH=arm64v8/ .
$ docker push your-username/multiarch-example:manifest-arm64v8
```

Answer (score 0):

have your dockerfile have this:

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9